# Are there any downsides to using power-ups?

Tags: cheats, angry-birds, angry-birds-friends

When I play Angry Birds Friends, I always try to complete the levels every week 100% power-up-free. Mostly, as intrinsic motivation (what's the point of achieving something if you do it by "cheating" via a bought power-up?)

However, there's also a smidgen of extrinsic motivation: does the game regard such "cheating" (e.g. getting a higher score via using a power-up) as a **tangible Bad Thing**?

- Does using power-ups **penalize your score somehow?**
- Does using power-ups make your power-up score be **ineligible for rankings among either friends or entire league**?
- Other tangible downsides of cheating by using power-ups?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Does using power-ups penalize your score somehow?

Don't have an official answer, but didn't see a single time when my scores were penalized despite extensive use of power-ups

> Does using power-ups make your power-up score be ineligible for rankings among either friends or entire league?

From experience, no. Even using the Wingman doesn't